# Similar function of `nl2br()` of PHP in JSP?

Tags: php, jsp

We use `nl2br()` function in PHP inserts HTML line breaks (`<br> or <br />`) in front of each newline (`\n`) in a string. How can achieve the same in JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, however, you can create something similar that you can construct yourself:

```
public static String nl2br (String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
}

// Use this way:
nl2br("Hello\nworld");

// This will return "Hello<br/>world";
```

Comment: Users in windows environment might send `\r\n` instead of a single `\n` and doing this will result in `\r<br/>` and some old OS X could also use a single `\r`. PHP's nl2br handles all of this combinations.

Comment: @GrowingBrick Oops, I am not sure if that works well. I tried, and I am unable to make the right one. So it needs to replace once for `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` right?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is to don't make a double `<br/>` when `\r\n` is encountered. You could use a regex or replace it for first.

Comment: @GrowingBrick Sure, trying it.